# How to show “No Result Found” If no data found in table - Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, filter

I want to show "no result found" in the angular 8 table when filter. Here is my sample code

```js
fromEvent(this.searchParam.nativeElement, 'keyup')
      .pipe(debounceTime(500), distinctUntilChanged())
      .subscribe((event: any) => {
        this.getUsers(event.target.value);
      });

getUsers(searchParam: string = '') {
    this.userService.getUsers(this.page, this.limit, searchParam).subscribe(

      (data: any) => {

        this.users = data.results;
        this.loading = false;
        this.totalRecords = data.totalRecords;
        this.limit = data.limit;
        this.totalPages = Math.ceil(this.totalRecords / this.limit);
      },
      (errors) => {
        this.loading = true;
        this.errmsg = errors.error.message;
      }
    );
  }
```

```html
          <div class="form-group has-search searchbox">
            <span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback"></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" #searchParam placeholder="Search" />
          </div>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a hidden div and display it using ngIf.
In your html:

```
<div class='empty-result' *ngIf="empty">
No result found.
</div>
```

In your .ts:

```
empty: boolean = false;
getUsers(searchParam: string = '') {
    this.userService.getUsers(this.page, this.limit, searchParam).subscribe(
      if (data.length === 0) {
      this.empty = true;
      } else {
       this.empty = false;
      }
      (data: any) => {

        this.users = data.results;
        this.loading = false;
        this.totalRecords = data.totalRecords;
        this.limit = data.limit;
        this.totalPages = Math.ceil(this.totalRecords / this.limit);
      },
      (errors) => {
        this.loading = true;
        this.errmsg = errors.error.message;
      }
    );
  }
```

You can set a timeout to hide the message after displaying it.

Comment: if "this.empty" is initial "true", for second request, if exist items, this param will remain "true" if not use "else { this.empty = false;}" . He can check directlly in template by totalRecords length

Comment: Show me the object you're retrieving if it's empty

Comment: I tried another method
Html:
 <table>
                <div *ngIf="empty">
                  <h4 style="color: red;">No result found.</h4>
                </div>

Ts:
 (data: any) => {

        if (this.totalRecords) {
          this.empty = true;
        } else {
          this.empty = false;
        }

Comment: try adding if (this.totalRecords.length == 0)

Comment: Showing Error
Property 'length' does not exist on type 'number'

Comment: if it's a number you have to check the default value; which is 0; so ==> this.totalRecords == 0